# how to return a pdf file in API and display with the help of angular4

Tags: angular, c#-4.0, angularjs-directive

I wants to create API to return a byte stream and display with the help of angular4

I am also created a Handler method in asp then that place is work but in API i don't  know how to return a byte please explain or suggest me

here code is handler

> public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>       {
>           try
>           {
>               string pdfName = context.Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString();

```
        var fullName = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(pdfName);
        byte[] bytes;
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pdfName);
        //string file = context.Request.QueryString["fileName"].ToString();

        bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fullName);
        context.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.Response.Charset = "";
        if (context.Request.QueryString["download"] == "1")
        {
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        }
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;//ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
    }
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: today i am create API and return a byte from pdf file but can not bind in angular 4 pleae help me code is here to  return a pdf in byte form public byte[] getPDF()
        {
            string filename = "D:/Shared/EShopX-DEMO/Docs/Drawings/WPF Question.pdf";
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            return bytes;
        }

Comment: this is solved here some problem because i will check that console to in bytes also contains some extra character then that is problem to binding but i am remove some extra character from start and end then is working so i am post here only remove extra character this.http.get('http://172.36.0.40/webServic/api/pdf').subscribe(data=>{ 
        this.listData  = data.text().substring(1,data.text().length - 1);

Comment: This is solved here some problem because i will check that console to in bytes also contains some extra character then that is problem to binding but i am remove some extra character from start and end then is working so i am post here only remove extra character 

    this.http.get('http://172.36.0.40/webServic/api/pdf').subscribe(data=>{ 
            this.listData  = data.text().substring(1,data.text().length - 1);  

    then to bind the pdf in html as pdf viewer tag if u not installed so install it first as command npm install ng2-pdf-viewer --save then to use

Comment: solution is 

    this.http.get('http://172.36.0.40/webServic/api/pdf').subscribe(data=>{ 
            this.listData  = data.text().substring(1,data.text().length - 1);  

                              `<pdf-viewer src="data:application/pdf;base64,{{listData}}" original-size="true"   stick-to-page="true" autoresize="true" show-all="true"  ></pdf-viewer>`